# How to understand about AutoFlush property of LogSource

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I have a category "MyCategory" and its AutoFlush property is true and Trace Listener is Flat File Trace Listener. I create a LogEntry and write it with category. Log will be written to file successfully.

If I change AutoFlush property to false and write a LogEntry, **I can't understand why it's not written to file by LogSource. (when AutoFlush=false)**

Answer (score 4):

In streams a [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2bw4h516.aspx)() forces the stream to clear his buffer to the underlaying object. e.g. a file! So you logger will automatically flush, after every LogEntry, so you can see the result in file immediately.

The stream will clear his buffer when:

- The buffer is full
- The stream is disposing
- ...

**Addition:**

LogSource keeps a list of LogEntries, with an Capacity of *x*. If the list of LogEntries > *x* => Write to File. That's the buffering with `AutoFlush = false`. It will only write, when the buffer is full, calling Flush or LogSource dispose.

`AutoFlush = true;` calls `Flush()` after every insert of LogEntry to force the writing to file. No buffering, if you want to call it so. That means, you will see every entry immediately, other then after *x* Entries.

Comment: I can't understand why it's not written to file by LogSource (when AutoFlush=false). Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I've added some more infos. Hope it helps.